# Is it possible to configure the Play Framework's CRUD module to respect @Column(unique=true) annotations?

Tags: hibernate, frameworks, playframework, crud, unique-constraint

I'm using Play's CRUD module to create a simple set of admin screens.  One of my models is User and I want to enforce a unique constraint on the email field.

The code looks like this:

```
public class User extends Model {
    @Email
    @Required
    @Column(unique=true)
    public String email;
```

The admin screen displays correctly - when I try to break uniqueness (by saving a user with an already used email) I get this error (in the browser):

```
Execution exception
PersistenceException occured : org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update

In {module:crud}/app/controllers/CRUD.java (around line 100)

96:
             } catch (TemplateNotFoundException e) {

97:
                 render("CRUD/show.html", type, object);

98:
             }

99:
         }


100:
         <b>object._save();</b>

101:
         flash.success(Messages.get("crud.saved", type.modelName));

102:
         if (params.get("_save") != null) {

103:
             redirect(request.controller + ".list");

104:
         }

105:
         redirect(request.controller + ".show", object._key());

106:
     }
```

Are there any tweaks I can make to use the CRUD module AND column uniqueness annotations?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a custom check and add to the email property in the User class.

```
public class UniqueCheck extends Check {

    @Override
    public boolean isSatisfied(Object validatedObject, Object value) {
        if (StringUtils.isBlank((String) value)) {
            return false;
        }
        return User.findByEmail((String) value));
    }

}
```

Then

```
public class User extends Model {

@Email
@Required
@MaxSize(value = 250)
@CheckWith(value = UniqueEmail.class, message = "Existing account has been found with this e-mail")
public String email;

}
```

Comment: One issue of this method is that when I edit an existing Record and save it, It will also tell me that account has been found. How can I let it only check when create a new item rather than modifying existing item ?

Comment: Check the id field, if null you know it's a new record.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like the system is doing just what you expected. The only thing I can imagine is patching the CRUD module to catch this exception and be nicer, but generally unique constraints are database-side constraints and can only be checked by trying to write to the database. So a unique constraint is not a validation annotation (which can be executed before writing to the database).

Comment: Yes, agreed the constraint is working as I'd like.  It's the patching in the CRUD module so I can give an elegant response to the user that I'm wondering about.  Maybe this is beyond the scope of a simple CRUD tool.